# Do smooth, injective maps preserve linear independence?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, differential-geometry, vectors

Let $\phi: U \to V$ be a smooth map, where $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and $V \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. Suppose $\phi$ is injective. Then, $\phi$ maps linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ contained within $U$ to linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Is this true? I think this property is used in one of my lectures, but I can't find a proof anywhere.

(Context: Although this doesn't have much to do with the question at this point, it might be helpful. This question comes up when defining curvilinear triangles for surfaces. A curvilinear triangle is defined as some set in the plane satisfying several conditions, and then a triangle for a surface is defined as the image of that triangle under a chart $\phi$. It seems to be the case that $\phi$ maps linearly independent sets to linearly independent sets, though I don't know why. This is from a course in elementary differential geometry, though the question is just basic linear algebra.)

Comment: what do you mean by a vector in this case?

Comment: Does $V$ contain the origin? because then some vector $x\in U$ could be mapped to it, making the answer a "no". Also, I don't see why $\phi$ couldn't, say, straighten a circular arc in $U$ (taken e.g. with all points lying at the same distance from the origin) into a segment in $V$ that lies entirely within a ray of constant latitude and longitude

Comment: A non-zero vector is an element of $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ 0\}$, @aldodecristo

Comment: @giobrach You're right, I think $V$ should not be allowed to contain the origin. The example of straightening a circular arc is also the "intuitive counterexample" that I thought of, but I couldn't be sure (because of the smoothness condition).

Comment: then the answer is no just consider the map $(x,y)\mapsto (e^x,y,0)$

Comment: Even "rigid" (affine) transformations provide counterexamples. Take for example $U$ to be some open ball and let $\phi$ translate it by some vector and rotate it by some angle along some axis. Then a circular arc of the type I described could be rotated in such a way that two different points lie on the same ray from the origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conjeture that a smooth injective map might send linearly independent sets to linearly dependent sets is immediately disproved, because as soon as $\phi(v)=0$ for some $v\ne0$, we have that $\{v\}$ is linearly independent and $\phi[\{v\}]$ isn't. Nor, in fact, is $\phi[\{v,w\}]$ for any $w$.

For another example, we can devise a function in the form $\phi(x,y)=(e^{ax}-b,e^{x+cy}-d,0)$ such that $\phi(1,2)=(1,0,0)$ and $\phi(-1,-1)=(-1,0,0)$. Namely, solve for the coefficients $$\begin{cases}e^a=1+b\\ e^{-a}=b-1\\ e^{1+2c}-d=0\\ e^{-1-c}-d=0\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}b=\sqrt2\\ a=\ln(\sqrt2+1)\\ c=-\frac23\\ d=e^{-1/3}\end{cases}$$

Since $a,c\ne 0$, this $\phi$ is injective.